# How can I set a listener to the android passwordToggle so it triggers an event when someone taps to show or hide their password?

Tags: android

I am using android.support.design:passwordToggleEnabled to allow the user to hide/show the password they are using to login.

I want to keep track of how often users are clicking on the android icon to toggle the password visibility.  How can I do that?

[Image showing android password toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0NCD.jpg)

Comment: Do you want to count how many times the passwordToggle is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `OnClickListener` on the `TextInputLayout`:

```
    final int[] count = {0};
    TextInputLayout til = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textinputlayout);
    til.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.textinputlayout:
                    // do what you want when user clicks on passwordToggle
                    count[0]++;
                    break;
                case R.id.editText:
                    // do what you want when user clicks on EditText
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Replace `R.id.textinputlayout` and `R.id.editText` with your ids.